# How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (e- E_k) = e?,E_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We note:

$$E_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{n!}, n\geq0.$$

It is known that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n = e.$$

How to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (e- E_k) = e?$$

(We can express this sum by $ E_n $?).

Comment: How exactly have you defined $e$? This is trivial given the definition that $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} E_n$, which is a frequent definition.

Answer (score 1):

$e - E_k$ is just $$\sum_{r=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{r!}$$

So $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(e-E_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac k{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{(k-1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{k!} = e$$

Answer (score 0):

You can express E(k) = e Gamma[1+k,1] / Gamma[1+k]. Then, the sum over k (from 0 to n) approaches n e. The sum of e over k (from 0 to n) is (n+1) e. Then (n+1) e-n e = e.

Comment: Please be more specific! Waiting elementary solution.